# How to change the default quantity of lines visible in debug mode?

Tags: node.js, v8, embedded-v8

It shows only 2 lines before and after the current statement. I would like to change the quantity of lines each time I press n (next) or c (continue). The function list(n), quoting the documentation, it says:

> list(5) - List scripts source code with 5 line context (5 lines before
>   and after)

[Debug Info - NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_info)

For example executing:

```
$: node debug app.js

break in c:\nodejs\app.js:3
  1
  2
> 3 var fs= require('fs');
  4
  5 console.log('Hello World!');
debug>
```

I want to change the default number each time I move on statements. Or, an opinion which would be the best way to do it ?

Comment: Why? What do you think you'll learn from that, that you can't learn from looking at your source code (which shows you *all* the lines around it)?

Comment: It's not a problem that I currently have with my code. It's just a curious thing that came up. And I was wonder If there was another way beside going straight to the source code of NodeJs to change that default setting.

Comment: It's also a question that makes no sense. Having more lines around the debug statement does nothing for getting your debugging done. I'm sure you could look at the sourcode for the list command and see how to fiddle with it, but it'd literally be wasting time that you can spend just debugging properly instead. You can drop into the REPL while debugging for deep examination, and you already have your source code open so you know where to look with much more insight.

Comment: If it wouldn't make sense it shouldn't exist the command _List(n)_ which, indeed, exist. Though, to be not much repetitive it should be intelligent to set it since then when you are debugging. I'm trying to know if there is someone who find himself in the same problem and if there is a way to change it, improve it or whatever.

Comment: you're debugging: you already know where all your breakpoints are. My point is that if you're debugging properly, this is not a thing you're ever going to need. Asking about it, sure, but the answer is really just "you don't need this, even if someone wrote it in a way that it can be done". You already have the `debugger` keyword in your source, you know  where it's going to trigger, you already have your source code open. You are the computer while debugging.

Comment: I agree with you. The debug tool is complete. But, is there a way to create this functionality that I'm talking about ? [gdb](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gdb_9.html) has it as _set listsize count_ Nodejs has a client that connect to V8 through a protocol. I'm curious about this.

Comment: fair enough, but then this is probably the wrong place to ask: have you asked over on https://github.com/nodejs/node already, or their developer mailing list? Because [search and research](/help/how-to-ask), then ask on Stackoverflow if that yields nothing.

Comment: I find it good to have the question here for the sake of the community. I was going to ask in the mailing list after done it here.

Comment: don't wait for one before doing the other: do it all at the same time. Worst case, you get the answer somewhere else before someone can answer you here, in which case you can simply provide the answer yourself here.

Comment: When the original javascript is in ES6 and debugger isn't, it would be great to see more lines.